# Increase Facebook Like Button Size

Tags: android, android-facebook

Am having facebook like button in my android app, But its coming in default size even though i have provided height and width in xml. How to increase the facebook like button height and width.?

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
 android:id="@+id/like_view"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: You can change image size in the resources . Write the code where image is set

Comment: am using default like view widget provided by facebook

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to scale the height and width of your View, use the xml attribute android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: am using default like view widget provided by facebook,